# How to extract and detach from an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How do I extract and detach the last item from NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly spelled out in the API. Look for the information in both NSMutableArray and the parent NSArray. (documentation layout confused me when I started)

```
id theLastObject = [myArray lastObject];
[myArray removeLastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last object with the `lastObject` method of the array. You can then use the `removeObject` method to remove it from that array.